# if a in my_friends.items()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code as follows:

```
my_friends = {
  "Jose": 6,
  "Rolf": 12, 
  "Anne": 6
};



for e, v in my_friends.items():

    a = ('Jose', 6);

    if a in my_friends.items():

        print("yes");
```

Running this code, you get "yes" printed 3 times. This is confusing because when you print my_friends.items(), you get [('Jose', 6), ('Rolf', 12), ('Anne', 6)] and if that is the case, shouldn't yes be printed once because ('Jose', 6) shows up once in the list that is my_friends.items() ? New to this so forgive this potentially ignorant question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you've given is without proper indentation, so let me fix that first:

```
my_friends = { "Jose": 6, "Rolf": 12, "Anne": 6 }

for e, v in my_friends.items():
    a = ('Jose', 6)
    if a in my_friends.items():
        print("yes")
```

Let me break that what you're trying to do. This will make it easier for you to understand what's going on.

1) A dictionary of three items is created.
2) The dictionary is iterated over using a `for` loop.*(for a total of three iterations)*
3) In each iteration, it is checked whether `('Jose', 6)` exists in the dictionary.
4) `('Jose', 6)` does exist in the dictionary, so `"yes"`
    is printed in each iteration.

If you want to check if `('Jose', 6)` exists in the dictionary, you can simply do the following **without the `for` loop**

```
if a in my_friends.items():
    print("yes")
```

Or if you really want to use a `for` loop, you can do the following:

```
a = ('Jose', 6)
for e, v in my_friends.items():
    if a == (e,v):
        print("yes")
```

*BTW, you don't need to write `a = ('Jose', 6)` inside the for loop, you can write it outside the loop as shown above. The point is it is redundant to assign the same value to `a` again and again in a loop. You can simply do it once outside the loop*

Comment: Thanks so much. If I want to use a boolean like "if e == 'Jose' " then I will have to use a for loop, correct? Like in this example? 
for e, v in my_friends.items():
  if v == 6:
    print("yes")

Comment: The thing is `my_friends.items()` returns a list of tuples, where each tuple is a pair like *(key, value)*. So `my_friends.items()` will return `[('Jose', 6), ('Rolf', 12), ('Anne', 6)]`. So technically `6` is not an element in the given list. It is, in fact, one of the members *(the second member in `('Jose', 6)`)* of an element of the list.

Comment: It is weird because if I run: if "Jose" in my_friends, print("hi"), then hi is printed. BUT if I run: if "Jose" in my_friends.items(), print("hi"), then hi is not printed. Confusing.

Comment: I get it from your last comment. Thanks u so much!! So if we run (if "Jose" in my_friends.items() ) it will not print becaaue "Jose is not an element. But when we run (if "Jose" in my_friends) it will run because my_friends represents the keys of the dict my_friends

Comment: `my_friends` is a dictionary. When you say `x in my_friends`, it will check if `x` is a key in the dictionary. Now `'Jose'` does exist as a key in `my_friends`, hence `'Jose' in my_friends` returns `True`. While `my_friends.items()` will return a list of tuples as explained in the previous comment.

Comment: Yes, exactly! @user3138766

Comment: Yea no worries :P

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating through `my_friends.items()` with `e` and `v` and yet you don't make use of these variables. All you're doing is to test if `('Jose', 6)` is in `my_friends.items()`, so it naturally does the same thing for each of the 3 iterations.

Just remove the loop and you're fine.

```
my_friends = { "Jose": 6, "Rolf": 12, "Anne": 6 }
a = ('Jose', 6)
if a in my_friends.items():
    print("yes")
```

Comment: Why does it iterate 3 times? Shouldn't it only iterate once and find a, and then report that back?

Comment: Because there are 3 items in the `my_friends.items()` tuple.

Comment: So I must misunderstand how things iterate. Doesn't it iterate each element? In this case each tuple? So it should iterate through each tuple and print yes once? I understand I am wrong but do not get it!

Comment: @user3138766 By using them `items` method of the dict `my_friends` you turn the dict into a list of tuples `[("Jose", 6), ("Rolf", 12), ("Anne", 6)]`. Since all you want to know is if the tuple `('Jose', 6)` is in the aforementioned list of tuples, you simply use the `in` operator to test it in an `if` statement. No need for a `for` loop here.

Comment: Then why does (for e, v in my_friends.items():
  if e == "Jose":
    print("6") ) not print 6 three times?

Comment: @user3138766 Because here you're actually making use of the variable `e`, which is assigned with the key of the `my_friends` dict for each of the 3 iterations. And of those keys, only one of them satisfies the `e == "Jose"` test in your `if` statement, so `print("6")` only gets executed once.

Answer (score 0):

x in y checks whether an element exists in the list. You dont need to loop this check.

```
a = ('Jose', 6)

if a in my_friends.items():

print("yes")
```

should be outside the loop and checked only once.

Comment: If instead we wanted to check with a boolean like: if e == "Jose", we would then need a for loop in order to iterate, correct?

Answer (score 0):

the reason you are getting 'yes' three-time is just that you are fetching all the items from my_friends now there are three items, now in the next line you are initializing a to ('Jose', 6), which will be done three times as well. 
and the same condition is checked and validated true since ('Jose', 6) is present in my_friends so you get 'yes' three times.

Comment: Could you explain it another way? I do not understand. If this is true, then why does for e, v in my_friends.items():
  if e == "Jose":
    print("6") not print 6 three times, and only one?

Comment: let me explain you line by line. 

   y_friends = { "Jose": 6, "Rolf": 12, "Anne": 6 }
## This is your dictionary of lenght of three elements which includes key and value.


for e, v in my_friends.items():  # this iterator fetches key and value from dictionanry in loop.
    a = ('Jose', 6)   # Here you are initializing variable a with tuple value ('Jose',6)
    if a in my_friends.items():  # Indentation of if statement indicates you are executing if inside for loop 
        print("yes")   # print statement.

Comment: 1. Now when code executes, it will loop through dictionary with the size lenght.
2. you are not using e,v in your code.
2. every time a will be intialize equal to ('Jose',6)
3. since value of a will always remain ('Jose',6) with every loop, your if condition will always true,
since when you execute check if a in dictionary items it looks for that tuple object in your dictionary with key and value match for all items.
thats why you are getting yes three time.

Comment: more important point here to make is indentiation of if statement and if conndition check both executed exactly with the size of dictionary.

Comment: Gotcha. So since e, v are not used below for loop, the code below for loop is being checked 3 times, and since e, v are not being utilized, the code continues to run even though a is in my_friends.items(). Yes?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are checking for the membership of an item `('Jose', 6)` for a complete iteration over dictionary `my_friends` and in each iteration it is `True` because of True membership (i.e. the item `('Jose', 6)` is a member of `my_friends`).

> **Note:** It does not matter how many times you're checking for the membership of same item inside collection.
>
> If it exists inside collection, you will always get `True` if you do membeship check using **in** operator.

Have a look at the below example.

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>>
>>> for item in l:
...     if 1 in l:
...         print('yes');
...
yes
yes
yes
yes
yes
yes
>>>
>>> 2 in l
True
>>>
>>> 7 in l
False
>>>
>>> # Dictionary example
...
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>>
>>> d.items()
dict_items([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
>>>
>>> list(d.items())
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
>>>
>>> ('a', 1) in d.items()
True
>>> ('a', 4) in d.items()
False
>>>
```

**Better solution** is to make your program like this.

```
>>> a = ('Jose', 6)
>>> for e, v in my_friends.items():
...     if a == (e, v):
...         print('yes');
...
yes
>>>
```